# Router as a SSTP VPN client

Tags: router, vpn, mikrotik, sstp

I would like to connect one office (let's call it HQ) to another (Field office) via VPN so that all users from the field office will have access to HQ network. HQ has already the possibility to be connected via VPN (SSTP). Right now individual users are connecting to HQ VPN but I would like to change it in that way, that's whole Field Office would be connected to HQ.

From what I have found, it could be done with the usage of the router that has the option to be a VPN client - to be specific SSTP VPN client. From what I have found, only Mikrotik is allowing so.

My question would be, which Mikrotik router (or maybe another company as well) would be best allow Field Office to connect to SSTP VPN. In the Field office, there are around 8 computers.

EDIT: As John suggested, I'm not interested in installing client apps for each individual, I would like to connect the whole office on a hardware level.

Comment: There are several solutions so this is an opinion question.  Software client app means everyone needs the app. Site to Site with hardware VPN works better.

Comment: Small business Cisco RVxx VPN routers will do this very nicely. I have one here, done site to site with it and also access with a client app (both).

Answer (score 0):

For MikroTik, it depends on throughput as to which router you'd need.  Pretty much all of them have the SSTP support you're looking for.